# wp_get_canonical_url showing first url of the post for custom page

Tags: custom-post-types, tags, page-template, plugin-wp-seo-yoast, rel-canonical

I have created a `tag.php` page in the theme. It's working perfectly. I am getting the tags post on the page.

Now I have added the below link to the `header.php` page.

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-US" href="<?php echo wp_get_canonical_url(); ?>"/>
```

The above code is showing the canonical URL perfectly on all the pages but when I open my tag page then it's not showing the canonical URL. It's showing the first URL of the post

Any idea what is the issue?

**tag.php** code below

```
<?php
   /**
   * A Simple tag Template
   */
   get_header(); 

?>  
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
   <main id="main" class="site-main">

    <section class="resource-container" id="light-header">


        <div class="container">
            <?php $tag = get_queried_object();?>
            <h1><?php echo $tag->name; ?></h1>
       </div> 
          
 </section> 

   </main>
</div>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because `wp_get_canonical_url` can *only* be used on posts, and cannot be used for tags authors archives etc.

> Returns the canonical URL for a post.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_canonical_url/

More specifically, no equivalent exists for tag archives because archives and listings do not have canonical URLs. A canonical URL indicates to a search engine the correct and canonical location of a piece of content, but an archive is not an item of content, it's a collection/list.

Instead, it would be more logical to use the archive URL of the queried term, say `get_term_link`:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/

Just keep in mind that this too is semantically incorrect, the `alternate` link rel is for specifying alternative countries and locales, not the canonical URL:

- https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2011/12/new-markup-for-multilingual-content
- https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/localized-versions?hl=en&visit_id=637940968921291027-2794865761&rd=1

If you're using a multilingual plugin then you will need to look up how they handle this or your tag will always refer to the current locale.

Comment: My aim is to show only the current URL. So I tried wp_get_canonical_url. Thank you for sharing the information, Let me check the above links

Comment: if that's the case then you shouldn't be using `alternate`, the `alternate` is for an alternative _different_ URL that is equivalent but in a different language. If the goal was to indicate to google that the page was in `en_US` then this is not the solution. This tag is for when you're on an english page but want to tell Google "this is also available here in spanish"

Comment: Little bit confused here. I have to show that the page is in en_US and it's ready in English.   My target audience is from the USA. That's the reason I am using that hreflang="en-US".

Comment: That link was shared by the SEO team and said I have to add it along with the page URL on each page. So I thought wp_get_canonical_url() is the right to show the current URL of the page.  Any ideas and suggestions for this?

Comment: `wp_get_canonical_url` is _only_ for single posts, not archives.

Comment: If your goal is to get the current URL, you should ask that instead, and the answer to that is not WordPress specific and is the same for most if not all PHP code